# What should i use to do a collision test it?

Tags: android, button, bitmap, collision, rect

I am developing a game. I would probably need to do some math in it. I have a character made out of about 5-6 bitmaps together. I want to check its collisions. For example if he hits a bullet, hit platform and all of this stuff. I also want to check if a bitmap is being pressed(like a button). I heard that a rect is good for this but I'm not sure how to use it. can anyone explain how to use the rect for it or if you have a better or easier idea.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914911/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i found out that the rect class has contains option.
for example:

```
    Rect r = new Rect();
    r.set(left, top, right, bottom);
    if (r.contains(x, y)){
        // this is where it will happen if you touch it
    }
    if (r.contains(r2)){
        //what happens if it collides with rect number 2
    }
//or check intersect        

        if(r2.intersect(r)){
//what happens if it collides with rect number 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Playing with graphics in Adroid](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) series of articles. Collision detection is covered specifically in [part 7](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-vii,220.html).

Comment: The link is broken, btw i'm using canvas, not open gl

Comment: Thanks. I was updating it too :P

Comment: Thanks im going to check it out :D

Comment: can you give me a tutorial just for the rect thing, i dont want to read all these pages, i just want to know if the player touches the rect, and if lets say rect A is colliding with rect B. thanks again