# Android 2D-pixel perfect collision library

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I'm working on a 2D four-side scrolling game and I am currently implementing collisions. I was surprised to see that there is no pixel-perfect collision library implemented in the standard library, and so I wrote my own collision "engine" with geometrical forms to represent non-geometrical figures. For now, it works fine, but I really want to know if there's a way to just get it all over with, thanks to a well-built library. If anyone knows of one, please share it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pixel-Perfect Collision Detection Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914911/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-android)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I ask for a specific library,  on the other hand , that person wants to know how to implement and use it. He already has all set to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look to [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/). You can see one video here about 2d pixel perfect collision:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abbXURuDaTo

Comment: Excuse me, I'm just in the middle of my game development and I realized there is no pixel perfect collision in AndEngine. -disappointing- do you know which external library I have to use?