# Changing the shape of tabs in android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to ask how to go about changing the shape of tabs in Xamarin for tabbed pages for android application. I know that this would obviously require a custom renderer, however which class do I inherit from? Do I inherit from the TabbedPageRenderer or the TabbedRenderer? Also, how do I know which function calls the rendering of the Tabs so that I can override it?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this would obviously require a custom renderer, however which class do I inherit from? Do I inherit from the TabbedPageRenderer or the TabbedRenderer?

If you want to change the shape of tabs, then you need to inerit your custom renderer from `TabbedPageRenderer`. Because only `TabbedPageRenderer` has `SetTabIcon` to override, which allows you to access current tab object.

> Also, how do I know which function calls the rendering of the Tabs so that I can override it?

What you need to override is the `SetTabIcon` method. In this method, you are able to set the custom view of current tab.

**Notes:** In order to let `SetTabIcon` get called, you will need to set the `Icon` of every sub page, otherwise `SetTabIcon` won't get called.

So, you can follow below steps to change the shape of your tabs:

1. Create a custom `TabbedPage` in PCL:

   ```
   public class MyTabbedPage:TabbedPage
   {
   }
   ```
2. Use it in your Page:

   ```
   <local:MyTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomTabbedPageDemo"
                x:Class="CustomTabbedPageDemo.MainPage">
       <!--Icon needs to be set in order to call SetTabIcon-->
       <local:Page1 Title="Page One" Icon="icon.png"/>
       <local:Page2 Title="Page Two" Icon="icon.png"/>
   </local:MyTabbedPage>
   ```
3. Create a `.axml` view file in `Resource/layout`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:background="@drawable/myshape"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"></View>
   ```
4. Define a custom shape xml file(`MyShape.xml`) in `Resource/drawable`, you can define any kind of shape you wanted:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
     <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
         android:angle="270"/>
   </shape>
   ```
5. Create Custom Renderer for your custom tabbed page, and override `SetTabIcon`:

   ```
   [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTabbedPage),
    typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
   namespace CustomTabbedPageDemo.Droid
   {
       public class MyTabbedPageRenderer:TabbedPageRenderer
       {

           protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
           {
               base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
               tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_view);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Optionally, you can remove the tabbar's background image by removing `android:background` of `Resource/Tabbar.axml`'s TabLayout:

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
       app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
       app:tabGravity="fill"
       app:tabMode="fixed" />
   ```

Here is the complete demo, you can refer to:[CustomTabbedPageDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/CustomTabbedPageDemo).

Comment: Thanks but I would like to change the shape of the tab if possible and not just the icon on the tab.  I would like to change them to custom shapes with almost no gap in between. Something similar to puzzle pieces fitted together and I would also like to have text titles shown on them. Do I still modify TabbedPageRenderer?

Comment: My sample didn't change the icon, but change the entire view of the tab by  `tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_view);`. You can use any view in `tab_view`.

Comment: any idea how to remove the gaps between the tabs and also how to remove the underline?

Comment: By `Something similar to puzzle pieces fitted together and I would also like to have text titles shown on them.`, it is not possible to use android view to accomplish that, not even in native android apps, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201960/shape-of-puzzle-for-custom-view/17202410#17202410) for explaination.

Comment: Aww. It would be good if it can be done especially since Xamarin allows for custom rendering. But thanks alot :D

Comment: @MrAsk removing the underline is possible, you can accomplish that by setting `app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"` to `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` mentioned in step 6.

Comment: Sorry I'm gonna ask this since I am new to android but how do you place your picture in an axml file? I created an axml file but it seems that all i can do is change its background color

Comment: Use ImageView to [display an Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/imageview/display_an_image/).