# Is there a way to get a pixel from a View object

Tags: android, bitmap, collision-detection

I'm working in a simple game, and having problems on collision detecting.
I've found [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914911/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-android) a method called `isFilled`

```
    private static boolean isFilled(int pixel) {
      return pixel != Color.TRANSPARENT;
    }
```

The argument `int pixel` comes from `bitmap.getPixel(x,y)`
Is there an equivalent method to `bitmap.getPixel(x,y)` for a View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [View.draw(Canvas c)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) and draw the View into a Canvas created from a Bitmap using [Canvas(Bitmap b](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)).