# Game Collision detection libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I can do 2d collision detection of boxes and circles ,but I have a question . How can I do collision detection in this situation (1,2).I am using libGDX game engine for creating games.

[image]

Comment: How is (2) defined? As a bitmap? Vectors?

Comment: So "bitmap", then. How is (1) defined? As a mathematical circle (center, radius), or also as a bitmap?

Comment: again bitmap ... which is better? mathematical cicle or bitmap ? it is easy get bitmap center and radius

Comment: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder. Math is easier, for me. For bitmaps, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914911/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-android

Comment: https://lh4.ggpht.com/Go0_Up1ufscBIWz2g0z-kh08ivvHRb51Nn9yOY2I53nV6WU1ZLD4adbJoAqDhJfmOw=h900     I think you know this game . how it understands that player and ground are collidered ?

Comment: @user3693550 ,probably its using box2d,the ground is a polygon and the tires of the car are circles , box2d is doing  all the job.

Comment: so the ground is not a bitmap?or bitmap can be polygon too ?

Comment: Its probably just a `Texture` that fits the `Polygon`. Posibly the `Texture` is a simple square and it is stretched regarding the hight of the current area. So both, the polygons and the view depend on this variable height, which could be generated randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixture (1) in your world should most likely be a `ChainShape`. ChainShapes are determined by an array of `Vector2` objects, the more you have, the smoother the `ChainShape` tends to be.

Without very tedious scripting, making a fixture from an image is done by putting vectors at relatively close points to make a shape that looks similar to the image.

Further information on how to create a `ChainShape` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381381/chainshape-in-box2d).