# Pixel Perfect Collision detection between a custom view and an ImageView

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, pixel-perfect

I have a CustomView and an Image view. The CustomView is a ball that moves around the screen and bounces off the walls. The Image is a quarter circle that you can rotate in a circle on touch. I am trying to make my game so that when the filled pixels from the CustomView cross paths with the Filled pixels from the ImageView a collision is detected. The problem that I am having is I do not know how to retrieve where the filled pixels are on each view.

Here is my XML code

```
<com.leytontaylor.bouncyballz.AnimatedView
    android:id="@+id/anim_view"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/quartCircle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/quartercircle"
    android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Bitmap imageOriginal, imageScaled;
private static Matrix matrix;

private ImageView dialer;
private int dialerHeight, dialerWidth;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // load the image only once
    if (imageOriginal == null) {
        imageOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.quartercircle);
    }

    // initialize the matrix only once
    if (matrix == null) {
        matrix = new Matrix();
    } else {
        // not needed, you can also post the matrix immediately to restore the old state
        matrix.reset();
    }

    dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quartCircle);
    dialer.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
    dialer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
            if (dialerHeight == 0 || dialerWidth == 0) {
                dialerHeight = dialer.getHeight();
                dialerWidth = dialer.getWidth();

                // resize
                Matrix resize = new Matrix();
                resize.postScale((float) Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float) imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float) Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float) imageOriginal.getHeight());
                imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);

                // translate to the image view's center
                float translateX = dialerWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
                float translateY = dialerHeight / 2 - imageScaled.getHeight() / 2;
                matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

                dialer.setImageBitmap(imageScaled);
                dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);

            }
        }
    });
 }
```

MyOnTouchListener  class:

```
private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                startAngle = currentAngle;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
    double x = xTouch - (dialerWidth / 2d);
    double y = dialerHeight - yTouch - (dialerHeight / 2d);

    switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
        case 1:
            return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 2:
            return 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 3:
            return 180 + (-1 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
        case 4:
            return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @return The selected quadrant.
 */
private static int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
    } else {
        return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }
}

/**
 * Rotate the dialer.
 *
 * @param degrees The degrees, the dialer should get rotated.
 */
private void rotateDialer(float degrees) {
    matrix.postRotate(degrees, dialerWidth / 2, dialerHeight / 2);

    dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

And my AnimatedView

```
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {

private Context mContext;
int x = -1;
int y = -1;
private int xVelocity = 10;
private int yVelocity = 5;
private Handler h;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 60;

public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    h = new Handler();
}

private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidate();
    }
};

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smallerball);

    if (x<0 && y <0) {
        x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = this.getHeight()/2;
    } else {
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;
        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
            xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
        }
        if ((y > this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) || (y < 0)) {
            yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
        }
    }

    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);
    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

}
```

My question is: How can I retrieve the filled pixels from both of these views, and pass them through a function that detects a collision.

Thanks in advance for the help!:)

Comment: `Pixel-perfect` and `Android` have never been good friends.

Comment: @Rotwang what would you suggest for collision detection of animated objects?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not into gaming. I suppose some kind of coordinate system  proportional to the screen density.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914911/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-android?rq=1) might help you.

Comment: @Nico Thank you for the help, but that does not help me much as the person asking that question already had the bitmap data which I do not know how to retrieve the filled pixels of the images.

Comment: I don't know much about gaming but you should check the fps you are getting, more the fps, more accurate would be the detection

Comment: @SarthakMittal Okay! I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to define "filled pixels". I assume you mean the non-transparent pixels. The easiest way to find those, is by converting your entire view into a bitmap and iterating through its pixels. You can convert a `View` into a `Bitmap` like this:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.measuredWidth,
            view.measuredHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable drawable = view.background;
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

You'd also need to get the absolute location of the views:

```
Point getViewLocationOnScreen(View v) {
    int[] coor = new int[]{0, 0};
    v.getLocationOnScreen(coor);
    return new Point(coor[0], coor[1]);
}
```

Then you just have to iterate through the pixels of each `Bitmap`, check their colors to know whether they're "filled", and also check whether they're overlapping based on their coordination inside the bitmaps and the absolute location of the views on screen.

Iterating through a bitmap's is done like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < myBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        int color = myBitmap.getPixel(x, y);
    }
}
```

But I must say, I don't think performing this sort of heavy computations on UI thread is really a good idea. There are dozens of much better ways to detect collisions than pixel-perfect checking. This will probably come out extremely laggy.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate your images with Array of points marking your border coordinates(and update them on move/calculate them based on origin) then you'll be able to decide whether oposing object are in touch or not(if any of oposing arrays share the same point)